# html template that won't center on desktop & mobile, and it is stretching a logo image

Tags: templates, gmail, html-email

I'm sure this is going to be a super simple fix, but I am not much of a coder, so I can't figure this out.

I've built out an html email template for the purpose of marketing, but I'm dealing with 2 issues:

1. The logo at the top of the email gets stretched out on desktop or when reading on a landscape mobile device.
2. The email is centered on mobile, but way off-centered on desktop. Everything is pushed super far to the right.

Here is the code I'm using (with sensitive info redacted):

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheetName = "test";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

  if (!sheet) {
    Logger.log("Sheet 'test' not found.");
    return;
  }

  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (!values[i][0]) {
      continue;
    }

    var email = values[i][0];
    var firstName = values[i][6];
    var category = values[i][8];
    var userFirstName = values[i][13];

    var today = new Date();
    var dayOfWeek = today.getDay();
    var hourOfDay = today.getHours();

    if ((dayOfWeek >= 2 && dayOfWeek <= 4) && (hourOfDay >= 8 && hourOfDay <= 18)) {
      var subject = "**EMAIL SUBJECT**";

      var body = "<html>";
      body += "<head>";
      body += "<style>";
      body += "@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {";
      body += ".oEQ55c { width: 100% !important; }";
      body += ".zhwgeb { width: auto !important; }";
      body += ".MHCHNe { max-width: 100% !important; }";
      body += ".top-image { width: 100% !important; height: auto !important; max-height: none !important; }";
      body += "}";
      body += "@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) {";
      body += ".desktop-container { max-width: 750px; margin: 0 auto; }";
      body += ".top-image { width: 100% !important; height: auto !important; max-height: none !important; }";
      body += "}";
      body += "</style>";
      body += "</head>";
      body += "<body>";
      body += "<div class='desktop-container'>";
      body += "<table style='background-color:#007b83;padding:0 20px' role='presentation' width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>";
      body += "<span style='padding-top:0;font-size:0;line-height:0;color:#007b83;background-color:#007b83;display:none;overflow:hidden;max-height:0'>";
      body += "qd2rcx9dnb83";
      body += "</span>";
      body += "</td>";
      body += "</tr>";
      body += "<tr>";
      body += "<td></td>";
      body += "<td align='center' valign='top' width='600'>";
      body += "<table width='600' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' style='width:100%;max-width:600px;background-color:#007b83' bgcolor='#007b83' role='presentation'>";
      body += "<tbody>";
      body += "<tr>";
      body += "<td>";
      body += "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' role='presentation'>";
      body += "<tbody>";
      body += "<tr>";
      body += "<td>";
      body += "<table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' style='border-collapse:collapse;background:#fff;background-color:#fff;width:100%' bgcolor='#fff' width='100%' class=''>";
      body += "<tbody>";
      body += "<tr>";
      body += "<td style='border-collapse:collapse;direction:ltr;font-size:0;text-align:center' align='center'>";
      body += "<div style='font-size:0;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%'>";
      body += "<table border='0' cellpadding='20' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' style='border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#fff;vertical-align:top' width='100%' bgcolor='#fff' valign='top'>";
      body += "<tbody>";
      body += "<tr>";
       body += "<td align='center' style='border-collapse:collapse;width:100%' class=''>";
      body += "<img src='cid:ii_lpu1iayc2' alt='fef66602f01e7e5581f338b673b532ca.png' style='-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; display: block; width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto; max-height: 100px; outline: none; text-decoration: none; margin: 0 auto;' class=''>";
      body += "</td>";
      body += "</tr>";
      body += "</tbody>";
      body += "</table>";
      body += "</div>";
      body += "</td>";
      body += "</tr>";
      body += "</tbody>";
      body += "</table>";
      body += "<table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' role='presentation'>";
      body += "<tbody>";
      body += "<tr>";
      body += "<td>";
      body += "<table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' style='border-collapse:collapse;background-color:white;width:100%' bgcolor='white' width='100%' class=''>";
      body += "<tbody>";
      body += "<tr>";
      body += "<td style='border-collapse:collapse;direction:ltr;font-size:0;padding-bottom:30px;text-align:center' align='center'>";
      body += "<table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' style='border-collapse:collapse;display:inline-table' width='100%' class=''>";
      body += "<tbody>";
      body += "<tr>";
      body += "<td style='border-collapse:collapse;direction:ltr;font-size:0;padding:0;text-align:center' align='center'>";
      body += "<div style='font-size:0;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;width:100%'>";
      body += "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' style='border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#fff;vertical-align:top' width='100%' bgcolor='#fff' valign='top'>";
      body += "<tbody>";
      body += "<tr>";
      body += "<td align='center' style='border-collapse:collapse;width:600px' class=''>";
      body += "<img src='cid:ii_lpu1i1t51' alt='buyerlink photo.png' style='-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: 0; line-height: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; display: block; font-size: 13px; height: auto; width: 100%; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto;' class=''>";
      body += "</td>";
      body += "</tr>";
      body += "</tbody>";
      body += "</table>";
      body += "</div>";
      body += "</td>";
      body += "</tr>";
      body += "</tbody>";
      body += "</table>";
      body += "<table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' style='border-collapse:collapse;display:inline-table' width='90%' class=''>";
      body += "<tbody>";
      body += "<tr>";
      body += "<td style='border-collapse:collapse;direction:ltr;font-size:0;padding:0;text-align:center' align='center'>";
      body += "<div style='font-size:0;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;width:100%'>";
      body += "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' width='100%' style='border-collapse:collapse'>";
      body += "<tbody>";
      body += "<tr>";
      body += "<td style='border-collapse:collapse;vertical-align:middle' valign='middle'>";
      body += "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' style='border-collapse:collapse' width='100%'>";
      body += "<tbody>";
      body += "<tr>";
      body += "<td align='center' style='border-collapse:collapse;font-size:0;padding:0 10px;padding-top:20px;word-break:break-word'>";
      body += "<div style='font-family:arial,sans-serif;font-size:24px;letter-spacing:0;line-height:normal;text-align:center;color:#202124' class=''>";
      body += "<span style='font-size:28px'>";
      body += "Take advantage of the holiday season with the best leads!";
      body += "</span>";
      body += "</div>";
      body += "</td>";
      body += "</tr>";
      body += "</tbody>";
      body += "</table>";
      body += "</div>";
      body += "</td>";
      body += "</tr>";
      body += "</tbody>";
      body += "</table>";
      body += "<table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' style='border-collapse:collapse;display:inline-table' width='90%' class=''>";
      body += "<tbody>";
      body += "<tr>";
      body += "<td style='border-collapse:collapse;direction:ltr;font-size:0;padding:0;text-align:center' align='center'>";
      body += "<div style='font-size=0;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;width:100%'>";
      body += "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' width='100%' style='border-collapse:collapse'>";
      body += "<tbody>";
      body += "<tr>";
      body += "<td style='border-collapse:collapse;vertical-align:middle' valign='middle'>";
      body += "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' style='border-collapse:collapse' width='100%'>";
      body += "<tbody>";
      body += "<tr>";
      body += "<td align='center' style='border-collapse:collapse;font-size:0;padding:0 10px;padding-top:18px;word-break:break-word'>";
      body += "<div style='font-family:arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:400;letter-spacing:0;line-height:1.4;text-align:center;color:#5f6368' class=''>";
      body += "Hey " + firstName + ",";
      body += "<br><br>";
      body += "Are you ready for 2024 and this holiday season? ❄️";
      body += "<br><br>";
      body += "My name is " + userFirstName + ", and I wanted to personally reach out to you as an official representative of <b>" + "**MY COMPANY**" + "</b>, the <b><i>" + "fastest growing lead generator in the U.S to date!" + "</i></b>!";
      body += "<br><br>";
      body += "We have been servicing the " + category + " industry for <b>10 years</b> and have provided our clients phenomenal results throughout. I would like to discuss with you how **MY COMPANY** has kept our clients' cost of marketing to <b>10-15%</b> all while <b>boosting closing rates by an average of 33%</b>. Do you have time for a quick 10-minute chat?";
      body += "<br><br>";
      body += "Here is a link to <b><u><font color='#3d85c6'><a href='**MY CALENDLY LINK**'>my calendar</a></font></u></b>. Let's connect! I look forward to meeting you. Stay warm!";
      body += "</div>";
      body += "</td>";
      body += "</tr>";
      body += "</tbody>";
      body += "</table>";
      body += "</div>";
      body += "</td>";
      body += "</tr>";
      body += "</tbody>";
      body += "</table>";
      body += "<table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' style='border-collapse:collapse;display:inline-table' width='90%' class=''>";
      body += "<tbody>";
      body += "<tr>";
            body += "<td style='border-collapse:collapse;direction:ltr;font-size:0;padding:0;text-align:center' align='center'>";
      body += "<div style='font-size=0;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;width:100%'>";
      body += "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' width='100%' style='border-collapse:collapse'>";
      body += "<tbody>";
      body += "<tr>";
      body += "<td style='border-collapse:collapse;vertical-align:middle' valign='middle'>";
      body += "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' style='border-collapse:collapse' width='100%'>";
      body += "<tbody>";
      body += "<tr>";
      body += "<td align='center' style='border-collapse:collapse;font-size:0;padding:0 10px;padding-top:18px;word-break:break-word'>";
      body += "<div style='font-family:arial,sans-serif;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;letter-spacing:0;line-height:1.4;text-align:center;color:#5f6368' class=''>";
      body += "Best Regards,";
      body += "<br><br>";
      body += "<b>Jonathan Borgia</b>";
      body += "<br>";
      body += "Business Development Representative";
      body += "<br>";
      body += "Phone: **MY PHONE NUMBER**";
      body += "<br>";
      body += "<a href='mailto:**MY EMAIL ADDRESS**' style='color:#3d85c6;text-decoration:none' target='_blank'>**MY EMAIL ADDRESS**</a>";
      body += "</div>";
      body += "</td>";
      body += "</tr>";
      body += "</tbody>";
      body += "</table>";
      body += "</div>";
      body += "</td>";
      body += "</tr>";
      body += "</tbody>";
      body += "</table>";
      body += "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' style='border-collapse:collapse;display:inline-table' width='100%' class=''>";
      body += "<tbody>";
      body += "<tr>";
      body += "<td style='border-collapse:collapse;direction:ltr;font-size:0;padding:0;text-align:center' align='center'>";
      body += "<div style='font-size:0;text-align:left;direction:ltr;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;width:100%'>";
      body += "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='presentation' style='border-collapse:collapse;vertical-align:top' width='100%' valign='top'>";
      body += "<tbody>";
      body += "<tr>";
      body += "<td align='center' style='border-collapse:collapse;font-size:0;padding:0;padding-top:30px;word-break:break-word'>";
      body += "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' role='button' style='border-collapse:separate;background:#007b83;border-radius:4px;line-height:100%;padding:8px 24px' class=''>";
      body += "<tbody>";
      body += "<tr>";
      body += "<td align='center' bgcolor='#007b83' role='presentation' style='border-collapse:collapse;background:#007b83;border:none' valign='middle'>";
      body += "<a href='**MY CALENDLY LINK**' style='display:inline-block;background:#007b83;color:#ffffff;font-family:arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold;line-height:1.4;letter-spacing:0;margin:0;text-decoration:none;text-transform:none' target='_blank' class=''>";
      body += "<span style='display:block;min-width:10px' class=''>";
      body += "Schedule a call";
      body += "</span>";
      body += "</a>";
      body += "</td>";
      body += "</tr>";
      body += "</tbody>";
      body += "</table>";
      body += "</td>";
      body += "</tr>";
      body += "</tbody>";
      body += "</table>";
      body += "</div>";
      body += "</td>";
      body += "</tr>";
      body += "</tbody>";
      body += "</table>";
      body += "</td>";
      body += "</tr>";
      body += "</tbody>";
      body += "</table>";
      body += "</td>";
      body += "<td>";
      body += "</td>";
      body += "</tr>";
      body += "<tr height='0'>";
      body += "<td colspan='3'>";
      body += "<span style='padding-top:0;font-size:0;line-height:0;display:none;overflow:hidden;max-height:0;color:#fff'>";
      body += "qd2rcx9dnb83";
      body += "</span>";
      body += "</td>";
      body += "</tr>";
      body += "</tbody>";
      body += "</table>";
      body += "</div>";
      body += "</body>";
      body += "</html>";        

      var inlineImages = {};
      inlineImages["ii_lpu1iayc2"] = DriveApp.getFileById("1TGepSmzaq6ddn4xX7Sg45YFFt2_4eSD-").getBlob();
      inlineImages["ii_lpu1i1t51"] = DriveApp.getFileById("1sUkZVlAhfSB320dAodInmXXwPVCZqBHY").getBlob();        

      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: email,
        subject: subject,
        htmlBody: body,
        inlineImages: inlineImages,
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I don't really know how to explain what I've tried since I don't have a sophisticated understanding of coding, but I've spent a good few hours tweaking and fixing things, and this is the last thing that I haven't been able to fix. I'm just hoping there's a simple fix that someone can help with.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to get the final HTML code please..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will fix it but you've written `font-size=0` instead of `font-size:0` in 2 places, this might be stopping the rest of the CSS on that line from loading so try replacing that?

Also instead of `body += "CODE"` on every line, you could just use
body += `CODE.... followed by another backtick at the end

Comment: Thank you for responding!

For the second part of your response: you're saying instead of this:
      body += "<tbody>";
      body += "<tr>";
      body += "<td>";
I could do something like this instead:
      body += '<tbody>;
      '<tr>';
      '<td>';

Is that right?

I fixed the 2 font-size discrepancies you pointed out, but unfortunately the problem remains.

Comment: No worries! Html actually doesn't need semi-colons at all. In javascript you should add semi-colons but it doesn't seem to raise an error if you don't but otherwise yes, 
body +=`
code
code
end of code`
I'll keep trying to find the error and let you know if I do.

Comment: @JonathanBorgia Looks like you've also written width='600' as opposed to 600px which might be throwing off the size of child objects, like the image. Do you know the resolution of the image? It would make it much easier to debug.

Comment: The image is 270px x 100px